# Wordprocessor Preset - AfterEffect: How to keep cursor blinking at end of line of text?

Tags: adobe-after-effects, video

First time using the Wordproccessor preset in AfterEffects, Trying to create the effect of typing on computer with the blinking cursor at the end. Had some success but don't know how to keep the cursor blinking once it reaches the end of the line of text? At the moment it just disappears at the end.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can animate your cursor layer to blink by just keyframing one single loop on the Opacity property, like below:
[image: Opacity animation]

Then, Option-Click the stopwatch for the Opacity property and you'll activate it for expressions. Twirl open the little menu at the end of the list and select `Property`->`loopOut`. You can select to either control it via keyframes or duration. If you don't edit the expression at all, `loopOut` will continue looping your keyframes til the end of the comp.
[image]